# Is it possible to anchor a Literal Block in YAML?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

What I'm doing is creating several Literal Blocks like the one below, and putting them on a list.

```
literal1: |
    line
    of 
    text and stuff

literal2: |
    ...
```

and now the part which I can't figure out is to put them on a list. I've figured that I'm going to use anchors and aliases but they don't seem to work on literal blocks.

Doing this doesn't work

```
literal1: | &literal1
    line
    of
    text and stuff
```

it spits out an error. And also I'd rather not have to create a dict

```
literals: &literal1
    literal1: |
        ....
```

for this to work. I'm sure theres an easy way to do this but I just cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 9):

Is this what you want to do?

```
literal1: &literal1 |
    line
    of 
    text and stuff

literal2: &literal2 |
    another line
    of text and new stuff

literals:
-  *literal1
-  *literal2
```

The following program will print ...

['line\nof \ntext and stuff\n', 'another line\nof text and new stuff\n']

```
import yaml

data="""
literal1: &literal1 |
    line
    of 
    text and stuff

literal2: &literal2 |
    another line
    of text and new stuff

literals:
-  *literal1
-  *literal2    
"""

pydata = yaml.load(data)
literals = pydata [ 'literals' ]

print ( type(literals), literals )
```

Comment: I can't seem to find evidence that this is valid YAML syntax. I'm wanting to do something very similar for GitLab CI jobs using yaml and this doesn't pass the validator.